# How to navigate to template class member via tag command

Tags: search, tags

I have a C++ template class `С` and its member function `foo()`.
I also have tags file generated with Exuberant Ctags.

I want to access this function via the `:tag` command, something like this:

```
:tag C::foo
```

However it doesn't seem to work for me. Inspecting tags file for understanding what should I have passed as `:tag` argument didn't help me.

Is it possible? How should I specify template class?

**P.S.** `:tag foo` works fine. The problem is that there a too many of them in different classes so it's hard to find appropriate tag in the taglist. It turned out the simplest way is to use `:tag C` and then finding `/foo` which is still a bit awkward.

Answer (score 3):

There are (universal?) tags options that can request functions names to be prefixed by full scope (namespace + class). Unfortunately, I can't remember which one it is among:

```
--c++-kinds=+f --fields=+imaSftn --extra=+q
```

Any way, I highly recommend universal ctags instead of exuberant ctags for C++. And BTW, in [lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags) (that I'm maintaining), you'll find a more ergonomic way to select which overload you wish to jump to.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can use `ts`:

```
:ts foo
 # pri kind tag               file
 1 F C f    foo               b.cpp
               class:B
               void foo(){
 2 F C f    foo               c.cpp
               class:C
               void foo(){
Type number and <Enter> (empty cancels):
```

You can see all matching elements, and select them. But I did not see any option to specify directly the parent element.

Comment: Please see my PS -- I have about a hundred of foo's and it's a pain to look through all the pages of `ts` to find my match